# Migración de bootstrap 3 a 4

Tags: javascript, css3, bootstrap-4, cakephp, bootstrap-3

Muy buenos días, acabo de cambiar los cdn de mi bootstrap, y se me dañaron algunas funciones de la pagina. 
Por ejemplo un select se convirtió en un  boton: 
[image: Select:]
Y tenia un wizard por así llamarlo, de forma horizontal : [image: Imagen 1]
Y al pasarme al bootstrap 4 quedo así de forma vertical:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Aquí les paso los codigos, estoy en cakephp por si sirve de algo
SELECT
Default.ctp

```
 <select class="selectpicker" data-width="fit">
                            <option  data-content='<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-co" value="es"></span> Español'>Español</option>
                            <option data-content='<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-us" value="en"></span> English'>English</option>
                        </select>
```

Myscript.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {...
$(function () {
        $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
    });

var ln = x = window.navigator.language || navigator.browserLanguage;
    if (ln.indexOf("en") == 0) {
        $('.selectpicker').val("English");
        lang = "en";
    } else if (ln.indexOf("es") == 0) {
        $('.selectpicker').val("Español");
        lang = "es";
    } else {
        $('.selectpicker').val("Español");
        lang = "es";
    }

    $.traducir();
...});


$('.selectpicker').on('change', function () {


    var ln = $('.selectpicker').val();
    if (ln == "English") {
        lang = "en";

    } else if (ln == "Español") {
        lang = "es";
    } else {
        lang = "es";
    }
    $.traducir();
});
```

Este no tiene estilos ya que todo se hace con bootstrap, js y ps la vista.

WIZARD

Default.ctp

```
<div class="circle" style="cursor: pointer;">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li class="linkBrowserHome activado scroller">
                        </li>
                        <li class="linkBrowserNeeds desactivado scroller">
                        </li>
                        <li class="linkBrowserStrategies desactivado scroller">
                        </li>
                        <li class="linkBrowserTools desactivado scroller">
                        </li>
                        <li class="linkBrowserExecution desactivado scroller">
                        </li>
                        <li class="linkBrowserResults desactivado scroller">
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

Mystyle.css

```
.circle {
    background-color: transparent;
    position: fixed;
    top: 90%;
    right: 60%;
    z-index: 200;
}
.circle ul{
    list-style: none;
    cursor:pointer; 
    cursor: hand;
}

.circle ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
    content: '';
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background-color: #FEFEFE;
    margin: 20px 30px;
    z-index: 10;
    border: solid 1px #B7B7B7;
    left: 50%;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
.desactivado:hover {
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.3);transform:scale(1.3);
}

.activado{
    box-shadow: 0 0 0em 13px #EA0B8C;
}
```

Myscript.js

```
$(".scroller").on("click", function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass("linkBrowserHome")) {
        $.mostrar("Home");
    } else if ($(this).hasClass("linkBrowserNeeds")) {
        $.mostrar("Needs");
    } else if ($(this).hasClass("linkBrowserStrategies")) {
        $.mostrar("Strategies");
    }
});

(function ($) {
$.mostrar = function (id) {
        $('.activado').each(function (index, element) {
            $(this).removeClass("activado");
            $(this).addClass("desactivado");
        });


        if ($("#div" + id).attr("id") !== $('div.principal').children('div').attr("id")) {
            $(".principal").css({'position': 'absolute'});
            $(".secundario").css({'position': 'absolute'});
            var htmlDivPrincipal = $(".principal").html();
            var htmlDivSecundary = "<div id='div" + id + "' class='row'>" + $("#div" + id).html() + "</div>";
            $(".secundario").html(htmlDivSecundary);
            $(".secundario").hide();
            $(".principal").height($(window).height() - 100);
            $(".principal").width($(window).width() - 100);
            $(".secundario").height($(window).height() - 100);
            $(".secundario").width($(window).width() - 100);
            $(".principal").animate({
                left: "-=1500",
                width: "100%",
                opacity: "toggle"
            }, {
                duration: 2000,
                queue: false
            });

            $(".secundario").animate({
                left: "-=1480",
                width: "100%",
                opacity: "toggle"
            }, {
                duration: 2000,
                queue: false
            }).promise().done(function () {
                $(".principal").css({'position': '', 'left': '20px', 'display': ''});
                $(".principal").height("");
                $(".principal").width("");
                $(".principal").html(htmlDivSecundary);
                $(".secundario").height("");
                $(".secundario").width("");
                $(".secundario").css({'left': '1500px', 'position': '', 'display': ''});
                $(".secundario").hide();
                $(".secundario").html("hola");
            });

        }
        $(".linkBrowser" + id).removeClass("desactivado");
        $(".linkBrowser" + id).addClass("activado");

    }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Tienes varias clases en tu código que no son de Bootstrap, muéstranos el CSS de tus estilos personalizados

Answer (score 0):

Lo que yo hago en estos casos es darme una vuelta por el enlace que comparte @Rabegi y por este otro http://www.arnoldgutierrez.com/migrar-bootstrap-3-bootstrap-4/. 
Si no entiendo del todo el cambio utilizo el siguiente link: http://upgrade-bootstrap.bootply.com/ que te ayuda a convertir tu codigo de bootstrap 3 al 4, espero te ayude.

Comment: `<select class="selectpicker" data-width="fit">
                        <option  data-content='<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-co" value="es"></span> Español'>Español</option>
                        <option data-content='<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-us" value="en"></span> English'>English</option>
                    </select>` ese es el código que me esta convirtiendo en un boton, la cosa es que no es de bootstrap original sino que es de bootstrap form helper, por lo cual al no ser de la version oficial, la pagina no la convierte a la version 4 ni esta documentado en la migración

Comment: lo único que se me ocurre es un método poco ortodoxo, pero que puede funcionar. 
Más no sé si tiene descargado el paquete de bootstrap o lo direcciona con el link de bootstrap en internet, si es el primer caso, pues darle estilo directamente a selectpicker a como lo venía manejando bootstrap 3

Comment: Jum entonces seria buscar el estilo del selectpicker de bootstrap form helper? 
Y una duda, que difiere entre si lo llamo por cdn o si lo descargue?

Comment: en que con el paquete puedes manipular tu los .css y .js, y por CDN es la manera más fácil pero no podrás trabajar sin conexión a internet, es decir si en algún momento fallan los cdn o les dan mantenimiento cambiara la apariencia de tu web, por el contrario si tu los tienes en tu proyecto, sera como tener cualquier otro .css (siempre estará allí y no cambiarán tus estilos)